# ngresource not filtering properly with oData based Rest Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, odata, ngresource

i have a web api based controller using MongoDb at back end.

```
    public class NodesRestController : ApiController
{
    private INodeService _nodeService;
    public NodesRestController(INodeService nodeService)
    {
        _nodeService = nodeService;
    }
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<Node> Get()
    {
        return _nodeService.GetAllNodes().AsQueryable();
    }
    [EnableQuery()]
    public Node Get(Guid id)
    {
        return _nodeService.GetNodeById(id);
    }
}
```

in an angular application my resource looks like

```
(function() {
'use strict';
var nodeServiceRoot = '/api/NodesRest/:id';

angular.module('common.service')
    .factory("nodeResource", ["$resource", "appSettings", nodeResource])

function nodeResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + nodeServiceRoot, {
        id: '@id'
    }, {
        "update": {
            method: "PUT"
        }
    });
}}());
```

Nodes Collection looks like multiple instances such below.

```
{
"_id" : LUUID("982d248a-ef2a-f94c-be93-96ff67ca1d3f"),
"Name" : "RTR1",
"IP" : "1.2.221.121",
"NodeGroup" : {
    "_id" : LUUID("36a38db3-830c-4a45-8b9c-63b16394f985"),
    "Name" : "Group One"
}}
```

i am trying to get all  the nodes where NodeGroup.Name = "Group One" but i get all the nodes back.

```
 var nodesInNodeGroup = nodeResource.query({ 'NodeGroup/Name': vm.CurrJob.NodeGroup.Name});
        nodesInNodeGroup.$promise.then(function (response) {
            nodesInNodeGroup = response;
        });
```

vm.CurrJob.NodeGroup.Name = 'Group One'

kindy help.

Comment: Change the line 'var nodesInNodeGroup = nodeResource.query({ 'NodeGroup/Name': vm.CurrJob.NodeGroup.Name});' to 'var nodesInNodeGroup = nodeResource.query({ 'NodeGroup.Name': vm.CurrJob.NodeGroup.Name});

Comment: Didnt worked. Still returning entire collection

Comment: You controller is not an `ODataController`.

Comment: Yes i figured that out moments ago. I would like to mark your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is not an `ODataController`.

Comment: My real problem is explained in 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574958/odata-filter-not-working-on-navigation-property-with-mongodb-and-web-api
kindly have a look